# Default routing to path with dynamic id

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using following routes to load my dashboard.

Issue is when i am navigating to `localhost:4200` it navigates to `localhost:4200/dashboard`.

But what i want here is, i wanna navigate to this `localhost:4200/dashboard/:id` instead of above one by default.

**app-routing.module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "dashboard",
    pathMatch: "full"
  },
  {
    path: "dashboard",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./features/dashboard/dashboard.module").then(
        m => m.DashboardModule
      )
  }
]
```

**dashboard-routing.module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "",
    pathMatch: "full",
    // component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  {
    path: ":vid",
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: { title: "Dashboard"}
  }
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to navigate to a pre-defined id or does the id come from somewhere else?

Comment: @Mike S. pre-defined id only

Comment: Well, what keeps you from defining it as `redirectTo: "dashboard/7"` then? Where 7 is the id you had defined.

Comment: Thanks @MikeS. it worked. I have used like this redirectTo: `${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app-VID'))}`.
But if i want to get this id from some service instead of LocalStorage.
is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to naigate to `localhost:4200/dashboard/:id`
then please provide change `dashboard-routing.module` to this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: ":vid",
    pathMatch: "full",
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  {
    path: ":vid",
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: { title: "Dashboard"}
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Edison, i have already went through this approach, but no luck.